# Show no link for empty data in Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<td><?php echo "<a href=\"".$row['link']."\" target=\"_self\">Link</a>"; ?></td>
```

I would like the Link to be hyper-linked only if there is a data['link']in MySQL table

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($row['link']) && !empty($row['link']))
    {
        echo '<td><a href="'.$row['link'].'" target="_self\">Link</a></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>Link</td>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: yea but now one problem, I still need the text Link to be shown not completely removed. The idea is just when there is a data a hyperlink is created if not just the normal text Link would be shown

Comment: @user12345678 just add an `else` clause and you're good to go ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structure of your table, it's not possible to say if this will work, but it is a good start:

```
<?php if(strlen($row['link']) > 0):?>
<td><?php echo "<a href=\"".$row['link']."\" target=\"_self\">Link</a>"; ?></td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an isset and trim + strlen check of 0 around the data, before wrapping the Link caption in an anchor tag.

```
$linkHtml = "Bloopdie";

// Add anchor tag only if there is data in the row
if (isset($row['data']) && strlen(trim($row['data'])) > 0) {
  $linkHtml = '<a href="' . $row['data'] . '">' . $linkHtml . '</a>';
}

echo $linkHtml
```